# How to access Environment properties in spring validator class

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, properties-file

I am working on a spring boot application to build a rest service. I have implemented a spring validator for validating request.

Now, I want to fetch error messages from properties file. But it didn't work.I found from validator API that "This interface is totally divorced from any infrastructure or context;"

I have tried below options. But, always getting env as *null*

```
@Inject
private Environment env;

@Autowire
private Environment env;

@Resource
private Environment env;
```

Is there any work around?

EDIT:
I'm using below code:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new RequestValidator());
}
```

EDIT2:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(e, "userName", "userName", "userName is missing.");

e.rejectValue("pswd", "invalid.pswd", "Password length must be more than 6 characters.");
```

Comment: Let me guess, you are creating a new instance of your validator instead of using a spring configured one. Also if you use a validator you should use the `reject` methods on the `Errors` object which does the message translation for you... So not sure if you are even using the validators in the right way.

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, modify your question.

Comment: As stated you are creating instances of the validator yourself, so how should spring inject dependencies? Configure it in your application context and simply inject it into your controller.

Comment: It's working!!! Thank you so much for your help!.... as you mentioned I'm validating as per EDITED2 section where I'm fetching "userName is missing." from properties file. Is it proper way?

Comment: No it isn't... You should have a `MessageSource` configured and simply do something like `errors.rejectValue("username", "missing");` (assuming the field is named `username`. Now if you have `username.missing=Username is missing.` in your configured message source it will be automatically resolved. I strongly suggest a read of the spring reference guide which explains this.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Can you please provide any url for MessageSource configuration?

Comment: The Spring reference guide or any I18N sample application that uses spring.